# Vector field, difference of partials equals 1

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

I'm trying to come up with other examples of $F_1$, $F_2$ such that:
$$\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial y} = 1$$

I know the standard $F(x,y) = (-\frac{y}{2}, \frac{x}{2})$ works, but I'm wondering if there are other vector fields satisfying this?

Comment: Yes, if you write $B = (F_2,F_1)$ then you're looking for functions $B$ with $\operatorname{curl} B = 1$. You have one solution,  $B_0=(x/2, -y/2)$; any other solution $B_1$ differs by a gradient since we would have $\operatorname{curl} (B_0 - B_1) = 0$